# When to apply rules of logarithms, order of operation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Sometimes I get a little confused with what order to do things in when it comes to $ln$ being raised to the natural base. For example $e^{\int -A\ln{x} dx}$ where $A$ is an arbitrary constant. Should this be rewritten as $e^{-A \cdot \int \ln{x} dx}$ or $e^{\int \ln{x^{-A}} dx}$ ?

I guess what I'm asking is, do you simplify using normal rules of algebra first or using rules pertaining to integrals?

Comment: The short (and not very helpful) answer is: It depends on what you want to achieve in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not matter:
$$e^{\int -\ln x}=e^{-1/x-C}=\dfrac1{e^{1/x+C}}$$

$$e^{\int -\ln x}=e^{-\int\ln x}=e^{-(1/x+C)}=\dfrac1{e^{1/x+C}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Both of your rewritings are correct.  Whether they are progress depends on what you intend to do.